# How to create a custom POST controller method for a DTO class?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, odata

I created a DTO class that is not mapped to any SQL table in the model:

```
public class FooDTO
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I created an entity set of this type in the model:

```
public override IEdmModel GetModel()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();

    builder.EntitySet<FooDTO>("FooDTOs");

    // ...
}
```

And created a custom controller:

```
public class FooDTOsController : ODataController
{
    private IDatasourceFactory datasourceFactory;

    public FooDTOsController(IDatasourceFactory datasourceFactory)
    {
        this.datasourceFactory = datasourceFactory;
    }

    // The GET is working great.
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var db = (MyModel)this.datasourceFactory;
        IQueryable<FooDTO> foos = db.Set<Foo>().Select(
            t => new FooDTO()
            {
                Id = t.Id,
                Name = "blah blah blah"
            });

        return Ok(foos);
    }

    // I am not getting here.
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Post(FooDTO entity)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("YEAH!");

        return Ok(entity);
    }
}
```

But the Post method is not being executed. I have tried many ways to define the `POST` method, but I cannot find one that works.

Posting some data into my controller, results in the following error:

> Cannot create an abstract class.
>
> Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated
>   in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class.
>
> Source Error:
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception
>   stack trace below.
>
> Stack Trace:
>   [MissingMethodException: Cannot create an abstract class.]
>      System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached, RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +138
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +105
>      System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceImpl(BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +1528
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture, Object[] activationAttributes) +191
>      System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, BindingFlags bindingAttr, Binder binder, Object[] args, CultureInfo culture) +27
>      System.Web.HttpRuntime.CreateNonPublicInstance(Type type, Object[] args) +82
>      System.Web.Configuration.HandlerFactoryCache..ctor(String type) +58
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.GetFactory(String type) +104
>      System.Web.MaterializeHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +262
>      System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +137
>
> Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.6.114.0

**UPDATE:** I am using the following PowerShell script to test the POST method:

```
$body = @{
    Id = 1;
    Name = "Blah blah blah";
} | ConvertTo-Json -Compress


$response = Invoke-WebRequest `
    -Method POST `
    -Uri "https://localhost/MyModel/FooDTOs/" `
    -ContentType "application/json" `
    -Body $body
```

Comment: - Can you use Fiddler Or Postman instead of powershell to hit the post ?       - Can you check if adding [FromBody] in front of  FooDTO parameter solves your problem ? i.e public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] FooDTO entity), which will try to look for your entity in the body of your message.